# unwind-protect - how does it work

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I am using sbcl 1.0.57.0 and want to start a program via `--eval` which should generate some output, but in case that there is an uncaught error it shall exit.

I figured the easiest way to accomplish that would be by using unwind-protect:

```
(unwind-protect (error 'simple-error) 
  (progn (FORMAT t "IAMREACHED~%") (sb-ext:exit)))
```

As `(sb-ext:exit)` should be executet incase there is an uncaught error.

But it doesn't!

```
* (unwind-protect (error 'simple-error) 

       (progn (FORMAT t "IAMREACHED~%") (sb-ext:exit)))

    debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
    #<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002979193}>:
    (A SIMPLE-ERROR was caught when trying to print *DEBUG-CONDITION* when entering
    the debugger. Printing was aborted and the SIMPLE-ERROR was stored in
    SB-DEBUG::*NESTED-DEBUG-CONDITION*.)

    Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:QUIT) to exit from SBCL.

    restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
      0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

    (#:EVAL-THUNK)
    0] 0
    IAMREACHED
```

What is my misconception about the workings of unwind-protect?

Comment: works for me on CCL, but shows the same problem on SBCL.

Comment: there is no uncaught error. The SBCL debugger caught it.

Comment: uncaught in the way that I did not explicitly caught it

Comment: You should put the call to `SB:EXIT` outside the `PROGN`. As you've written it, `SB:EXIT` is called after the `FORMAT`, and there are no unwind forms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`UNWIND-PROTECT` is an analogue of `finally` clause in Java or Python, so it's not a catch-all clause, that will intercept any unhandled condition. For that you need a `HANDLER-CASE` with a handler clause for type `CONDITION`.

`UNWIND-PROTECT` actually works in your case. The only "unexpected" behaviour is that the debugger is invoked **before** the body of `UNWIND-PROTECT` is executed. The reason for this is not to lose the current context and be able to restart execution. It is (probably) achieved via `HANDLER-BIND`. You can learn more about that in PCL chapter ["Conditions and Restarts"](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-exception-handling-conditions-and-restarts.html).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to disable the debugger, see [SBCL Toplevel Options](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/Toplevel-Options.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use (ignore-errors) for the purpose of silently omitting errors.
Or you could call sb-ext:disable-debugger early to only see error message without the debugger launch.